# Running a python script on a linux machine after every few minutes, only if its not already running

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a python script which has to run once every 3 minutes. The script runs a process can run for more than 10 minutes though. And hence I need to make sure that if it's already running it shouldn't run. I need to do this without any database interference.
The approach I have used it is having a cron via the following command in the crontab.

```
*/3 * * * * sudo ps aux|grep -v grep|grep "python XMLProcessor.py"
|| cd /home/ubuntu/git/perpule-python-subscriber; sudo python XMLProcessor.py
```

It runs smoothly. But the problem here is, once in a while, even after the process ends, the command **sudo ps aux|grep -v grep|grep "python XMLProcessor.py"** still gives an output because of which the python script doesn't run.

Please suggest me a better approach or rectify the one I'm using. All the suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using has some problems as ps can report "unexpected things". Are you sure that your python program has a unique name? Could it be that there are race conditions (it could run the program twice)?

A typical way of doing this is to touch a file at the start of the process and remove it and the end of it:

`if [ ! -f .working ]; then 
  touch .working && \
    python do_something.py && \
    rm .working
fi`

Then you can check if it's working by checking for that file. However, there are multiple problems with this approach: what happens if the process crash? should you remove the touched file? is it possible to remove it for  every possible crash?. Then you need to add timeouts, and it starts getting complicated.

The proper and safer solution then is to use some sort of server or tool that checks that your job is being run, and if not it runs it. I have used [luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) to do something similar and it integrates quite well with python code, so you could give it a try.

Comment: Luigi seems interesting. Can I know what did you use it for? And how that task is similar to what mine is?

Comment: I have used it for DB/Filesystem backups using python code. Everyday a backup process is started if it's not being run already (luigi checks that). Backups can take more than a whole day if a lot of data was generated that particular day. I think is similar because it does not matter if its run every day or every minute, luigi will ensure that only one instance of the job is being run.

Comment: Just saw this. I went through luigi today, but I'm unable to figure out how to ensure if a condition while running the first task isn't met,  the second(dependent) task is not triggered. Any idea on it?

Comment: You require a task from another one. task1 requires on something (for instance a file to exist), and the tas2 requires task1.  Have a look at [triggering-recurring-tasks](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/luigi_patterns.html#triggering-recurring-tasks)